# Store value in Session or cache in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to like this but it is showing error that session is undefined

JS

```
this.locationId=event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
        Cache.Session.put('ns1.partition1.orderDate', this.locationId);
        let locid ;
        if (Cache.Session.contains('ns1.partition1.orderDate')) {
            locid = Cache.Session.get('ns1.partition1.orderDate');
        }
```

how i can do this

Answer (score 3):

The classes and methods you are using are from the apex developer guide and in no way related to lightning web components.

Are you trying to store data client side? If so, you are better of using local storage or variables to manage the client side state.

[client-side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage)

Comment: how can i do this by local storage

Comment: Please go through the linked documentation to learn how to store on the client